# Display specific data with parameter using Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Hi I have error in regards with my displaying specific data. I passed a parameter through a model and I get error on regarding creating a new instance. here is my code:

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ViewEmployeeSalary(spGetSalaryPerEmployee getsal)
    {
        var salary = _Context.Set<spGetSalaryPerEmployee>().FromSql("spGetSalaryPerEmployee @empID = {0}", getsal.EmployeeID).AsNoTracking();
        return View(salary);
    }
```

**View**
This the button where you click to redirect to the details page

```html
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-controller="Salary" asp-action="ViewEmployeeSalary" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Salary Details</a>
}
```

Here is the page where it views the details

```html
@model PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.spModels.spGetSalaryPerEmployee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Salary Details";
}

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)'s Salary Details</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="form-horizontal">ID:</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.EmployeeID)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="form-horizontal">Salary Amount:</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Salary)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="form-horizontal">Remarks:</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Remarks)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I get this error:

[image: error]

I don't really what really happens but stated the I need to create an instance.
I have still a little knowledge about asp.net core and ef core and still studying for this language for now.  I really need your help in regards with this since I'm a bit new with this language.

Any suggestion would be a greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do not insert images of error messages, but the text instead. By linking images you won't get hits from the search engines for this error.

Comment: Please don't force tags into question titles. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method needs to return single record as error states. Now it returns a list, so you need to change to something like this:

```
    var salary = _Context.Set<spGetSalaryPerEmployee>().FromSql("spGetSalaryPerEmployee @empID = {0}", getsal.EmployeeID).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault();
    //salary now is single record
    return View(salary);
```

And maybe you need to check `salary` variable is not `null` before passing it to view, because then you'll have errors there.

Comment: Hi @Mantas, the code seems work but I redirected to a blank page and I don't know why.  I tried to check the asp-action and it seems nothing wrong with it.  Can you take a little look on my code?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in a view, is it being hit? Is the view with details shown first an then it redirects to blank? or it goes straight to a blank page?

Comment: I did put a break point and it seems it didn't went through my ViewEmployeeSalary class. It seems weird to me since I checked both controller and action.

Comment: Ohhh... Sorry I removed the         `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and changed `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` and It works like a charm right now... Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear ;)